# sqs public queue(read/delete) limit possible expenses

Tags: amazon-sqs

I'm willing to share a queue to allow 3rd party to use it for read/delete messages but I want to be sure this won't be abused(i.e. limit max expenses)

What is the best way to do this without making a wrapper API on top of sqs?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Furthermore, unless you 100% trust that 3rd party I wouldn't allow them raw access to your queues as it opens you up to abuse/mistakes.

- What stops them putting random garbage in the queue?
- What stops them purging the queue?
- What stops them interacting with the queue badly? i.e. reading but not deleting messages

If you trust them enough with the above then you can trust them to not abuse your usage limits.

You should control access to your system through an API that you control.  You can handle all of the above including putting rate limiting in place.

Alternatively setup a CloudWatch alert when reads/writes/deletes go above a certain limit and contact your 3rd party to tell them to slow down.

Comment: afaik I can allow only specific calls to be available to public usage, like only read/delete message api calls. I do not need an absolute protection vs the abuse, just something that would allow me to feel safe enough and lower my risks. The cost of hosting own wrapper API is just too high for me(scalability, fault-tolerance - price is skyrocketing). Currently I'm thinking of using CloudWatch to gather queue usage stats and revoke public access from the queue if a threshold is reached.

Comment: That still requires a level of trust you need to be happy with - presumably your 3rd party is putting messages on a queue for you to process? If so, you need to be sure they're doing the right thing.  If you only really want them to have write access you could setup SNS/Lambda and do rate limiting that way

Comment: My software running on ec2 populates the queue and manages its life-cycle, while I want to provide read-only access to the 3rd-party(read/delete api calls)

Comment: In that case CloudWatch is your friend.  It would be useful to ensure your 3rd party also isn't being silly and makes use of long polling/back-off etc.